# Azure Graph API Trigger 2FA/MFA Auth Request

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, multi-factor-authentication

Using Azure Graph API how do I trigger a 2FA push?

For example, Duo has an API `/auth/v2/auth` which triggers a push/SMS/phone call/passcode request to a user. https://duo.com/docs/authapi#/auth

Twilio supports this via their "Verify v2" endpoint `https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/{ServiceSid}/Verifications` https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification

Where is Microsofts?

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/879158/rest-api-to-enable-mfa

Comment: @Rukmini Gotcha so there is NO way for me to have an admin at my work push a button and the users device will light up and ask them to MFA. This would be used as a step in identity verification.

Comment: Well I hesitate only because that question asks about enabling/disabling MFA. It does not ask about sending an MFA prompt.

Comment: MFA is triggered every time when you log in if the Azure AD user has MFA enabled

Comment: @Rukmini But I cannot build a .NET Core web app, or a PowerShell script that would trigger an MFA prompt remotely, correct?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: @Rukmini If you comment that as the answer I will accept.

Comment: Sure I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: MFA is a part of the user journey, and it cannot be triggered, it can only be enabled. Refer this [**Microsoft Q&A**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/573203/sending-manual-mfa-prompts) by *Jai Verma*. MFA is triggered every time when user logs in and if the Azure AD user has MFA enabled

- Only when a user tries to access an application configured to trigger MFA, MFA be triggered.
- Or if the user is enabled MFA.
- MFA cannot be triggered from Azure AD side remotely.

*You can enable MFA either by Azure Portal, PowerShell or Conditional Policy.*

For ***sample***, using PowerShell you can enable MFA:

```
$mf= New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement
$mf.RelyingParty = "*"
$mfa = @($mf)

Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "ruk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $mfa
```

[image]

When I tried to login with the user, got MFA prompt:

[image]

**References:**

[Trigger/Invoke MFA request for specific user via PowerShell or other tool? - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad/trigger-invoke-mfa-request-for-specific-user-via-powershell-or/m-p/2741066) by ChrisAyers

[Rest API to enable MFA - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/879158/rest-api-to-enable-mfa) by AmanpreetSingh-MSFT